# Calculating change to a customer

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function

I'm trying to make a function that creates a table to show the amount of change for each currency needed, eg. $50;1 $20;2 50cents;1 and so on. This function I just need to return the amount due, and number of each currency, the table will be displayed in another function.

What's the best way to go about this?

due = $40
values = new Array(100,50,20,10,0.5,0.2,0.1);

function calculateChange(due, values)

Comment: It is a basic programming 101 [modulus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) question.

Comment: Just having trouble with where to start

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is very simple: You have an array of banknote and coin denominations, sorted in descending order. Look at the denominations in that order and see how many coins of that denomination you have to give out. Reduce the leftover change accordingly.

Here's one implementation that returns a dictionary whose keys are the denominations and whose values indicate how many items of that denomnation are included in the change. Items ehose value is zero are not included in the dictionary:

```
function change(amount, coins) {
    var res = {};

    for (var i = 0; amount > 0 && i < coins.length; i++) {
        var value = coins[i];

        if (value <= amount) {
            res[value] = Math.floor(amount / value);
            amount -= value * res[value];
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

For example:

```
c = change(431, [5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 200, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]);
// c == { 1: 1, 10: 1, 20: 1, 200: 2 }
```

Note how the coin denominations are given in cents throughout. If you use the more natural-seeming dollar representation, you'll get floating-point numbers and you may run into rounding issues. (Numbers in Javascript are floating-point numbers, but  if they represent integers in a certain range, which should suffice for your problem, they are accurate.)

Comment: Thanks I am using  larger numbers so no floating point numbers. My function is actually already passing in the arrays (amountDue) and (values). Could you explain your example function a bit I'm still confused about it.

Comment: You can walk through the function step by step to understand it better. There is a big loop that considers all coins in decreasing order. When a coin value isn't larger than the amount, one or more coins have to added to the change. When you have to hand out $4.05, you first hand out 2 two-dollar bills. The rest of the change is $0.05, so you consider all of the coins with values smaller than $2 until you hit the five-cent piece. After that you're done.

Comment: The additional condition `amount > 0` is not strictly needed, but it cuts the loop short when the desired amount has been handed out. (It also catches negative amounts gracefully be retuning an empty dictionary.) The notation `x -= y` means the same as `x = x - y`, which may have confused you.

Comment: I tried to run your code as its hard to understand without seeing it but i'm just getting a blank page

Comment: How do you run the code? It doesn't print anything on the HTML document. You could print the result with `console.log` and check the console.

Comment: I tried this console.log  (change(50,50,20,10));
function change(amount, coins) {


var res = {};

    for (var i = 0; amount > 0 && i < coins.length; i++) {
        var value = coins[i];

        if (value <= amount) {
            res[value] = Math.floor(amount / value);
            amount -= value * res[value];
        }
    }

    return res;
 }

Comment: Just returns  Object {}

Comment: I tried putting this into my script                                           function calculateChange(amountDue, currencyValue) {

function calculateChange(due, values) {
  var remains = due;

  for (var currentValue in values) {
    if (remains/values[currencyValue[i]]>1) {
    change[values[currencyValue[i]]] = Math.floor(remains/values[currencyValue[i]]);
   remains = remains%values[currencyValue[i]];
    }
  } 
return change;
}